# JavaScript Alert in Android WebView working only at first time

Tags: android, android-webview

I am new to Stack Exchange and Andorid development.

I am working on Android webview. I have the following code in my activity class.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    WebView wv;
    WebSettings ws;

    try {
      wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
      ws = wv.getSettings();

      ws.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
      ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

      wv.clearCache(true);
      wv.loadUrl("http://<ip address>:<port>/<context>");
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

in layout-main.xml:

```
<WebView 
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />
```

in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".POCActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

In the url I have index.html with the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Contact Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert("Start");
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Database 1</p>
    <div id="test"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Working Environment:
  - Eclipse indigo
  - Android SDK min version 10
  - Build Target 2.3.3

But the android code is working only once i.e. when I create a new android project and run the same, I can see the javascript alert appearing. From next time the javascript alert is not displayed. Even is any text changes(Say I modified "Database 1" to "Database 2") in the html page is also not displayed.

I tried the following:
  - Cleared appcache
  - Uninstalled the application and then ran the project again
  - Cleared

Please let me know what I am doing wrong here. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

Used these on my code and then my alert() worked pefectly

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old question, but I recently encountered the same problem and would like to share the solution to anyone who come across this later.

You will need to assign a custom WebChromeClient to your WebView to handle the alert.

```
mWebView.webChromeClient = object : WebChromeClient() {
    override fun onJsAlert(view: WebView?, url: String?, message: String?, result: JsResult?): Boolean {
        val alertDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                    .setMessage(message)
                    .setPositiveButton("OK") { dialogInterface, _ ->
                        dialogInterface.dismiss()
                        result?.confirm()
                    }
                    .setOnCancelListener { result?.cancel() }
                    .setCancelable(true)
                    .create()
        alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true)
        alertDialog.show()

        //Here AlertDialog is just an example. You can also simply show a Toast.
        //But remember to call JsResult.confirm() or JsResult.cancel()

        return true
    }
}
```

You need to call either `JsResult.confirm()` or `JsResult.cancel()` to notify your WebView whether the user confirmed or canceled the alert dialog. Otherwise, the WebView would assume an alert dialog is still showing(blocking the UI) and won't allow a new one to be shown.